# recursively fill a column in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a Pyspark Dataframe with the following columns

| CD | CD_PRE | OBJ_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | null | 1 |
| 456 | 123 | 2 |
| 789 | 456 | 3 |
| 098 | null | 1 |
| 765 | null | 1 |
| 432 | 765 | 2 |

What i need to do is check if the value in the "CD_PRE" column is in "CD" column until i reach the row where "CD_PRE" is empty and "CD" is the "CD_PRE" from the previous row. Then, i have to create a column and populate with "OBJ_ID" from the row where "CD_PRE" is empty.

In summary, this is the desired result

| CD | CD_PRE | OBJ_ID | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | null | 1 | null |
| 456 | 123 | 2 | 1 |
| 789 | 456 | 3 | 1 |
| 098 | null | 1 | null |
| 765 | null | 1 | None |
| 432 | 765 | 2 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat unclear. Try the following.

```py
from pyspark.sql import Window
import pyspark.sql.functions as F


(
    sdf
    .select(
        F.col("CD").cast("DOUBLE"),
        F.col("CD_PRE").cast("DOUBLE")
    )
    .withColumn(
        "RESULT",
        F.when(
            F.col("CD_PRE") == F.lag(F.col("CD")).over(Window.partitionBy(F.lit(None)).orderBy(F.lit(None))),
            1
        )
        .otherwise(None)
    )
).show()

+-----+------+------+------+
|   CD|CD_PRE|OBJ_ID|RESULT|
+-----+------+------+------+
|123.0|  null|     1|  null|
|456.0| 123.0|     2|     1|
|789.0| 456.0|     3|     1|
| 98.0|  null|     1|  null|
|765.0|  null|     1|  null|
|432.0| 765.0|     2|     1|
+-----+------+------+------+
```